# How can I autoadjust the table height, width in LaTeX with many pages of text

Tags: tables

I am using CentOS and TeX Live. I am new to LaTeX.

This is what I am trying

```
\documentclass[landscape, letter]{report}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=0cm,top=.5cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\title{titulo}
\author{Rodrigo Coster - 1141783-01}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\textbf{{\LARGE Relação de vagas autorizadas, providas e disponíveis}}\end{center}
\tiny
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
    \hline

        \textbf{ number }

           &


        \textbf{ name }

           &


        \textbf{ parentt }

           &


        \textbf{ status }

           &


        \textbf{ date }

           &


        \textbf{ bank\_statement\_no }

           &


        \textbf{ bioregion }

           &


        \textbf{ cond\_notes }

           &


        \textbf{ Impl\_notes }


    \\
    \hline




            be416f8rererec23

               &


            From C1, it follows that relational information does not affect the structure of the levels of
acceptability from fairly high (e.g. (99a)) to virtual gibberish (e.g. (98d)).

               &


            For any transformation which is sufficiently diversified in application to be of any interest, this
analysis of a formative as a pair of sets of features is, apparently, determined by a stipulation to
place the constructions into these various categories.

               &


            Draft

               &


            2013-04-27

               &


            ed802ec655d485161a6fe02a5a325cd9

               &


            Norrtrhrerren rererereley

               &


            Note that the notion of level of grammaticalness is unspecified with respect to nondistinctness in
the sense of distinctive feature theory.

               &


            We have already seen that the earlier discussion of deviance appears to correlate rather closely
with nondistinctness in the sense of distinctive feature theory.


        \\
        \hline




\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This is giving me the croped table but I want all the text on one page.

Now

1. I can have the rows like 100s of rows and can span 50 pages
2. My Columns can also vary so i don't know what is the good way to handle that.
3. There will be many paragrahs of text in many columns so I want to have nice looking table

I am trying since morning I am not able to figure out what to use `tabular`, or `tabularx` or `y` or `resizebox`

Everytime I search google I find new way of doing it.

The max I can go is A3 size in landscape mode so that  it fits all data.

Can anyone please tell what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `longtable` package (available [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable)) for a table spanning over several pages, `tabularx` (available [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)) for selecting the proper width of your columns and finally, if you want to use both properties, you can always use the `ltxtable` (available [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable)) to have both the tabularx and longtable options.

You can also use the `tabu` package, but I strongly advise you not to do so, since his author has stated that the new version is not going to be backwards compatible and could have many problems with other packages compatibility.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltxtable}

\begin{document}
Hello.

\LTXtable{\textwidth}{VersionOne}

\end{document}
```

Where the `VersionOne.tex` file contains:

```
\begin{longtable}{XX}
\caption{A very long table}\\
WHO                 & \hspace{5mm} World Health Organization\\[1mm]
GDP                 & \hspace{5mm} Gross Domestic Product\\[1mm]
PPP                 & \hspace{5mm} Purchasing Power Parities\\[1mm]
\label{tab:LongtableOne}
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: i am new to latex , can you give me example for my case how to use `ltxtable`

Comment: Done, but please don't forget the read the ltxtable documentation, as provided in the link above

Comment: thanks for that , i could find the latex link above. Is it possible to put all in one file. i am using pdflatex to convert that so i don't know if that will find the other file

Comment: I don't think that is possible.  You shouln't have any problem with pdflatex (I'm actually using it), but you should use a separate file.

Comment: i tried your example as its is and its working. so if replace with 15 columns and 100 rows , will it auto adjust the height and width

Comment: As with many things in LaTeX, running an experiment and seeing how it looks is perhaps the best "testbench"

Comment: Length wise its is ok but widthwise  its only showing 2 columns and its cropping all other 7 coulmns.how can i auto adjust table cell width

Comment: Did you change the argument of `\begin{longtable}{XX}` of the example to the number of Xs as your code?  Keep in mind you need as much Xs as columns you are about to input.  Also **as described in the ltxtable documentation**, you can set the width by the importing command: `\LTXtable{width}{file}`

Comment: Sorry buddy , i chnaged it back to XX. now i am showing the centre of columns and i ahve 96 pages. but the columns width is very less. Is there any way to increase the width of page with scroll bar. thanks for your help

Comment: You can change the page style to landscape, but I'm not sure if this will continue to work with ltxtable.  Try it :)

Comment: My table is showing in the center. is there any way to go to left corner. also where is the ltxdocumentation , i could not find link